# eclipse EE html class hint

Tags: html, eclipse, hint

[netbeans picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS7QU.png)I was working on netbeans, it will give the hint if I type class=". How to config that in eclipse(java EE version)?

I already config the content assist for html file.

Answer (score 0):

You can always look for Eclipse plugins that can add certain code snippets and hints for your work! 
You can also install Eclipse [Web Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/), if you haven't already!